# Adobe APIs: Ability to edit text in PDF documents

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe

Adobe extract API allows to extract the complete content of the PDF document and gives `StuctureData.json` in return along with images, tables content. This is all good!

Now, i want to edit this extract content and resave/restore back to the PDF document, could not find any API that can do it.

There's PDF Extract API which extracts info into JSON but not sure how to resave PDF using changed text?

Comment: Its really tough to redact in PDF, its a one way road. Best way to convert PDF-> Word (edit) -> PDF (Quality of PDF is quite bad). Looks like even Adobe is clueless in what they have created :D